# jQuery 1.8: unsupported pseudo: hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.8

The following code raises the error `unsupported pseudo: hover` on jQuery 1.8, while it works perfect on jQuery 1.7.2:

```
if(!$(this).parent().find('ul').first().is(':hover')) {
   $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: probably a bug with the rewritten Sizzle?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087093/hover-selector-doesnt-work-with-jquery-1-4) question.

Comment: There is no such a selector in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: `:hover` worked for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Tm77a/) testing with jQuery 1.8 and Firefox, but _didn't_ work for me in IE with jQuery 1.7.2 _or_ 1.8 (but the actual error message in IE was different between 1.7.2 and 1.8).

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, while we all wish that our code were future proof, your `$('foo').on( 'hover, ... function(){ //do stuff }` code is [deprecated in jQuery 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731).  I wish I had better news for you, but your code is broken because of a core change to jQuery 1.8.  You now have to use the syntax

```
$('.selector').on( 'mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('hover');
   }
);

if(!$(this).parent().find('ul').first().hasClass('hover')) {
   $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
}
```

Wish I had better news for you, but deprecation happens :/ ... jQuery 1.8 doesn't like your shortcut and they've deprecated the `hover` event handler from `.on()` and also the pseudo-selector `:hover`, so it can't be used that way any more.

Comment: Or `$('.selector').hover( function() { $(this).toggleClass('hover'); } ); ...`

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but for anyone googling:

A workaround for this is to go the other way round:

`$(":focus, :active").filter($(".your-element"));`

…because `.filter()` also accepts jQuery objects, this will match any elements with the pseudos `:focus` and `:active` that also have the class `.your-element`.

In other words, if `.your-element` isn't hovered or active, this selection matches no elements.

Answer (score 2):

weird - for me, .is(":hover") is still working in 1.8, but broken in 1.9.1.

Anyway, here is a fix

```
function mouseIsOverWorkaround(what){
    var temp = $(what).parent().find(":hover");
    return temp.length == 1 && temp[0] == what;
}
```

then call above function on the "naked" (non jQuery-wrapped) element. In your case,

```
if(!mouseIsOverWorkaround($(this).parent().find('ul').first()[0]) {
   $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
}
```

(don't forget the [0])

the above-mentioned (comment to orig question) fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Tm77a/ does not work in jQuery 1.9.1

fiddle with this one http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/BxL4w/