# How to make mouseleave function stop when the mouse is hover a specific div

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, mouseout

This is the HTML code :

```
<div class="item">item 01</div>
<div class="item">item 02</div>
<div class="item">item 03</div>
....

<div class="list">
   <ul>
       <li>store 1</li>
       <li>store 2</li>
       <li>store 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now how it works :

when I Hover to "item 0X" the "List" should diplaying next to button "item 0X" and this Works fine.

the problem is how to make the list stay visible when I come back from the list to the button again.

I try to use this code but it doesn't works

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            var div = $(this);
            if( $('.list').css('display') == "none" )
            {
                actionHover(div);
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            setTimeout( function(){
                if( $(".list").is(':hover') )
                { 

                }
            else if( $(".item").is(':hover') )
            { 

            }
                else
                { 
                    $('.list').hide();
                }
            }, 100)
        }
    },".list, .item");
```

And when the mouse get out from list it makes an error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo:
>   hover

http://jsfiddle.net/y2KcC/3/

Comment: you are using the id "item" several times. ids must be unique! also, depending on what jquery version you have, :hover is buggy. just google, first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998514/jquery-1-8-unsupported-pseudo-hover

Comment: If all you want to do is hide `.list` when the user is not hovering on `.list` or `.item`, take out that whole `setTimeout` portion and just leave the `$('.list').hide();` - your mouseleave is already triggered by each.

Comment: Goose:Your answer is Correct , but this makes a little problem, when I paste from the button to list the list hide fast so i need to paste very fast to catch the list from hiding... any idea ?!

Comment: Is this intended to be a dropdown? or would the list be displayed somewhere else on the page? Whenever you mouseout of your specified elements, the mouseleave function will trigger - so you'll most likely need to put these elements inside of a parent element and trigger the mouse events on the parent element.

Comment: it's a list to store the items in a specifics stores. so when you display a list of items and you hovering some item this list should appear to select a store for the hovering item.

Comment: if this a dropdown kind of menu or something similar, it would make sense to put the list as a child of item. Since you are not using any animations, using css alone could solve your problem

Comment: I use "costume scrollbar" script so I had to make the container of "items list" overflow:hidden:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you'd like to do, try something like this:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).children('.list').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).children('.list').hide();
    }
}, ".item");
```

This would require that you have the list as a child element of `.item`, and that mousing over/out the parent `.item` would be what shows/hides each list.

[Here is a sample, with the markup also adjusted.](http://jsfiddle.net/46A5v/)

**Edit**

Ok, I cleaned up your code and removed the `setTimeout` function. After that it looks the issue you're having is not that the list disappears but that it is trying to move again once you mouseover it. I adjusted it so that it only changed position if you were mousing over the `.item` element. As shown below:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('item')) {
    $('.storeList').css({'left': (left + btn_wtd) , 'top': top });
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2KcC/4/).

Comment: thanks Goose, why Im not using the list as a children, that because the div parent of "items list" has an overflow: hidden; so the list of store can't be shown correctly when you try to select a store for the last item in list. and here when I get the "store list" out, and by this method the list display correctly out of the "items list" box

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle that has **all** of your markup and styling? I think this would help me better understand.