# .slideUp() and slideDown() on mouseover() issue - for each element differently

Tags: jquery, hover, slidedown, slideup

Current question is extension of [$(".someclass").is(":hover") works well for only single "someclass" instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473352/someclass-ishover-works-well-for-only-single-someclass-instance)

below jquery snippet works allready well for http://jsfiddle.net/4x661tt6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").mousedown(function() {
      if ($(".title").is(":hover") || $(".helper:hover").length ) return;
      $(".helpers").slideUp(); //slideToggle();
  });
  $(".title").mouseover(function() {
    $(".helpers").slideDown();
  });
});
```

my next problem is to make it run with http://jsfiddle.net/4x661tt6/1/ (recognize document mouse clicks excluding ".title" ".helper"), and in addition, to make each title trigger to slideDown() its owned childs differently...

Now, after source extension of another menu, *hovering* at any ".title" slidesDown() both instances, and background *clicks* stopped being recognized

---

edit: ive changed return line for

```
if ($(".title:hover").length || $(".helper:hover").length ) return; //is(":hover")
```

and it recognizes now more ".title" instances .... i coulded dig it earlier!

now only problem is to slideDown each ".title" differently, and Ill be at home

Comment: "This works here, now I want to make it run in there" isn't a proper problem description. Have you tried something to fix the issue or are you simply posting questions one after another...?

Comment: Read the question before commenting. There are no absolute positioned elements.

Comment: I actually get a runtime error in the second example saying "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover"

Comment: I don't see any code with slideUp/Down.. what's your question again? You already fixed the hover problem.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie that was a useless side-note. I just said "Read the question before commenting" because obviously, you didn't read it. If you had read it you should have seen there is a `table`, some `div`s and no positioned elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is(":hover")` will only work on a single instance.

Try this bit:

```
$("body").mousedown(function() {
   var isHovered = !!$('.title, .helper').
                filter(function() { return $(this).is(":hover"); }).length;

   if (isHovered)
     return;
  alert( 'triggered' );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxfok6mv/1/

Comment: I have allready solved that by `if ($(".title:hover").length || $(".helper:hover").length ) return;` but your solution is probably better. Now I need to do `$(".title").mouseover(..` to work for each ".title" differently  /there isnt related jsfiddle snippet, but its unnecesary, i believe its common issue

Comment: Ok most part of question was solved, I can accept your answer. It was fast issue, sorry if you dont like easy ad hoc problems here;

Comment: I'm starting to believe that perhaps the method is a bit backwards for what you want to accomplish.  Ie, why care about the body click if what you want to do is open a menu on hover?   The markup provided in the fiddle doesn't really explain a hidden menu of sorts with sliding/toggling.    I'd be happy to try further if you put up some markup of what you actually want to happen with the elements hidden until invoked/etc.

Comment: check http://siwego.net (top page), you will see my intention;
its lightweight solution that works perfectly to my need